# How to get the result from javascript on RadGrid_ItemDataBound

Tags: telerik, radgrid, rad-controls

Hi all I am having where I will have a filed called **ApprovalStatus**. If this is **N** I would like to show a popup showing do you want to approve this employee. If **Ok** I would like to edit and update the status to **Y** and then allow user to edit the selected row.

This is what I written

```
protected void RadGrid2_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
    {
        int iPagecount = RadGrid2.MasterTableView.CurrentPageIndex;
        if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
        {
            if (iPagecount == 0)
            {
                if (e.Item.ItemIndex != 0)
                {
                    GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)e.Item;
                    ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton)item["imgEdit"].Controls[0];
                    imageButton.Visible = false;
                    //imageButton.ImageUrl = "images/MailOk.png";
                }
                else
                {
                    GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)e.Item;
                    ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton)item["imgEdit"].Controls[0];
                    imageButton.Visible = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)e.Item;
                ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton)item["imgEdit"].Controls[0];
                imageButton.Visible = false;

            }
        }

        if (e.Item is GridEditableItem && e.Item.IsInEditMode)
        {
            GridEditableItem item = e.Item as GridEditableItem;
            mlocal_strStoredProcName = StoredProcNames.Gender_uspGenderGetList;
            oEmployeePersonalData.Select(out mlocal_ds, mlocal_strStoredProcName);
            Label lblStatus = (Label)item.FindControl("lblApprovalStatus1");
            if (lblStatus.Text == "Y")
            {
                if (!e.Item.OwnerTableView.IsItemInserted)
                {
                    Label LBL1 = (Label)item.FindControl("lblMaritalStatus");
                    RadComboBox rdcmbGender = (RadComboBox)item.FindControl("rdcbGender");
                    rdcmbGender.DataSource = mlocal_ds;
                    rdcmbGender.DataTextField = TablesAndColumns.tblGender_GenderDesc;
                    rdcmbGender.DataValueField = TablesAndColumns.tblGender_GenderTypeID;
                    rdcmbGender.SelectedValue = (string)DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "MaritalTypeID").ToString();
                    //rdcmbGender.SelectedValue = LBL1.Text;
                    rdcmbGender.DataBind();

                    mlocal_strStoredProcName = USADAO.StoredProcNames.PayFrequency_uspPayFrequencySelect;
                    oEmployee.FedTaxID = Session["FedTaxID"].ToString();
                    oEmployee.Select(out mlocal_ds, mlocal_strStoredProcName);
                    RadComboBox ddlPayFrequencytype = (RadComboBox)item.FindControl("rdcbPayFrequency");
                    ddlPayFrequencytype.DataSource = mlocal_ds;
                    ddlPayFrequencytype.DataTextField = "PayFrequencyDesc";
                    ddlPayFrequencytype.DataValueField = "PayFrequencyType";
                    ddlPayFrequencytype.DataBind();
                    ddlPayFrequencytype.Enabled = false;
                    mlocal_ds.Clear();
                    RadDatePicker radDtStartDate = item.FindControl("radDtStartDate") as RadDatePicker;
                    RadDatePicker radDtEndDate = item.FindControl("radDtEndDate") as RadDatePicker;

                    strDate = radDtStartDate.SelectedDate.Value;
                    EndDt = radDtEndDate.SelectedDate.Value;
                }
            }
            else
            {

                rdwndwPersonal.RadConfirm("Are you sure?", "confirmCallBackFn", 300, 100, null, "My Confirm");  // Here If **OK** was clicked I would like to set **e.Item.Edit = true;** if cancel was clicked I would like to set **e.Item.Edit = false;**
            }
        }
    }
```

But I am unable to achieve as per required can some one help me.

Comment: can you please specify what technology are you working on ? is this RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX/MVC/WPF/WinForms ???